# Parsing HTML in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, html-parsing

I'm using [poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin) to trigger Jenkins jobs based on incoming emails.

One of the build parameters (`pmt_content`) contains the body of the email specified in HTML.

Is there a Jenkins plugin that can parse the HTML and retrieve the values of user-specified tags?

Email content example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style='margin:20px'>
    <p>The following user has registered a device, click on the link below to
    review the user and make any changes if necessary.</p>
    <ul style='list-style-type:none; margin:25px 15px;'>
        <li><b>User name:</b> Test User</li>
        <li><b>User email:</b> test@abc.com</li>
        <li><b>Identifier:</b> abc123def132afd1213afas</li>
        <li><b>Description:</b> Tom's iPad</li>
        <li><b>Model:</b> iPad 3</li>
        <li><b>Platform:</b></li>
        <li><b>App:</b> Test app name</li>
        <li><b>UserID:</b></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Review user: https://cirrus.app47.com/users?search=test@abc.com</p>
    <hr style='height=2px; color:#aaa'>
    <p>We hope you enjoy the app store experience!</p>
    <p style='font-size:18px; color:#999'>Powered by App47</p><img alt='' src=
    'https://cirrus.app47.com/notifications/562506219ac25b1033000904/img'>
</body>
</html>
```

Specifically, how could I retrieve the value of the "Identifier:" tag?

I'm sure I could write a script to do it but I'd rather the logic in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a Jenkins plugin that can parse the HTML and retrieve the values of user-specified tags?

Its a one-liner on the shell or few lines in the scripting language of your choice. But seems, thats not what you are looking for.

In general, no, there isn't a plugin for the purpose of parsing HTML and retrieving the value of a tag, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins

> How could I retrieve the value of the "Identifier:" tag?

There is a generic plugin called [Conditional BuildStep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin),
which supports regular expressions on parameters.

When the HTML Email content is in `pmt_content` you could use the following 
RegExp

`<li><b>Identifier:<\/b>(.*)<\/li>` to extract the value `abc123def132afd1213afas` (or match and exec another command, if found).